# Accessing native gps from a website

Tags: gps

I have developed a web site that can detect user location using html5 navigator.geolocation. But the accuracy is very poor, average accuracy reported back from navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() is 1KM even though I set the option to high accuracy {enableHighAccuracy:true}.

But I know the phone itself can provide much better accuracy. When I use other Google apps, the position is dead on.

Can I access to the phone's native gps directly from a web site running on the browser?

Thanks!